# Nested include in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, join

How to perform nested include ?
I have table products that has one to many relation with comments, and table comments has many to one relation with users table.
So comments has user_id, and product_id.
My code is like this

```
var models = require('../models');

models.products.findAll({
    include: [
        {model: models.comments}
    ]
  }).then(function (products) {
    next(products);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    next(err);
  });
});
```

I get the comments, but I would like to have something like

```
models.products.findAll({
    include: [
        {model: models.comments.include(models.comments.users)}
    ]
  })
```

Is this possible without writing custom queries ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
models.products.findAll({
  include: [
    {model: models.comments, include: [models.comments.users] }
  ]
})
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: This solution does not work as written (at least not in the version I have, 3.24.1). The inner include should be 'include: [models.users]'.

Comment: Be carefull if this is a many-to-many association. In this case you should use `hasMany` when define association.

Answer (score 12):

Solution provided didn't work for me, this is the typescript version I use and guessing the sequelize versions:

```js
// sequelize-typescript
models.products.findAll({
  where,
  include: [{
    model: Comment,
    include: [User]
  }]
});

// without typescript (guessing here)
models.products.findAll({
  where,
  include: [{
    model: models.comments,
    include: [{
      model: models.users
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: This seems to compile, but I have an error on my side : column X->Y.link dos not exist. But I have in X : HasMany Y and in Y I have BelongsTo X. I don't understand why I can't include this way in typescript sequelize

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple and concise way! https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#including-everything

```
// Fetch all models associated with User
User.findAll({ include: { all: true }});

// Fetch all models associated with User and their nested associations (recursively) 
User.findAll({ include: { all: true, nested: true }});
```

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps someone in the future:

I was nesting multiple levels deep, and I kept getting Typescript errors that my call didn't match any overrides.

For me, it was not clear in the previous answers (or the docs) that you **must** wrap the `include` object in an array at all levels (even in you only provide 1 object).

Works:

```
User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Contact,
    include: [{
      model: Address,
      include: [{
        model: City,
        include: [State, Country]
      }]
    }]
  }]
});
```

Does NOT Work:

```
User.findAll({
  include: { // <-- notice the missing square bracket
    model: Contact,
    include: { // <-- notice the missing square bracket
      model: Address,
      include: { // <-- notice the missing square bracket
        model: City,
        include: [State, Country]
      } // <-- notice the missing square bracket
    } // <-- notice the missing square bracket
  } // <-- notice the missing square bracket
});
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use `include`.

For example :

```
Category = sequelize.define(...);
Product = sequelize.define(...);
Product.belongsTo(Category, {foreignKey: 'fk_category'});

Product.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Category
    }]
});
```

Will retrieve the nested Category, and not just the id, in a `category` property.